# Running bash commands in two terminals (client/server sides) via python in an anaconda environment

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter

I am having a problem in running a bash command via python and a anaconda environment that the required packages have been installed in the environment. One command acts as server side and start a database and another command should be run in client side in **another terminal** which has been activated for the same anaconda environment.

How can I run these bash commands separately in a separate terminals in Python?

Is it possible I open client side terminal and activate the anaconda environment, and send the command through `os.system()` to that specific terminal? If yes, how?

As you can see, in one terminal the following command starts the database:

```
(my_env) esara@esara-XPS-8920:~/workspace/$ ./command_ -start ./home/db/
```

and in another terminal I am running the following command:

```
(my_env) esara@esara-XPS-8920:~/workspace/$ ./command_ -query ./path/to/a file/
```

How to run these scenario in Python?

Comment: This is not possible, at least not cleanly. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The code is running in the bash in the client side (via python `os.system`) that I am loading its results into python into a list. I need that each of these two bash commands(1:calling database in server side, and 2:a specific command in client side) can be run in two different terminal commands inside python. Does terminal has a identity/key in python that we specify which command should be run in which side (client/server)?

Comment: I am having a very hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Do you want to execute a command on a remote server and then process the results?

Comment: I apologize for poor English. I want to run two different bash commands in python in a way that it should be run in two different terminals.

Comment: Just on one computer? Why do you want it to open another terminal? Is your actual problem running two commands at once? Also, what commands are you trying to run?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes it is in one computer, this is a C++ code that I have downloaded and compiled so the nature is like that and I need it to use in python. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible in a reasonable way. You will just need to open and start the programs seperately